# First Fundamental Theorem of Calculus Domain

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

Suppose $F:[-1,4]\to\Bbb R$, $F(x):=\int_{-3}^{2x^4+x^2+1}{e^{-t}}$, $x \in [-1,4]$. I want to find a formula for the derivative without the integral symbol.

So I know how to do this by splitting the integral up to give: $F(x):=\int_{0}^{2x^4+x^2+1}{e^{-t}} =\int_{0}^{2x^4+x^2+1}{e^{-t}} +  \int_{-3}^{0}{e^{-t}}$. Then the second integral has derivative $0$ and then you define a composite function for the first integral with upper limit $x$ and a function mapping $x$ to $2x^4+x^2+1$. My question is that I know I have a problem because I need to prove the functions are continuous on $[-1,4]$ but the lower limit $-3$ is outside the domain.

So what do I do ? Do I say the integral can't be evaluated since $-3$ is outside the domain, or do I split the $\int_{-3}^{0}{e^{-t}} = \int_{-1}^{0}{e^{-t}}+\int_{-3}^{-1}{e^{-t}}$ and ignore the $\int_{-3}^{-1}{e^{-t}}$ ?

Cheers.

Comment: The integral is defined on the whole real line. Just apply FTC and Chain Rule for differentiatioin.

Comment: Your splitting is useless (your fixed lower bound does not need to be $0,$ it can as well remain $-3$ as it is). And you seem to confuse the lower bound for $x$ (i.e. the domain of $F$) with the lower bound for $t$ (i.e. for the integration interval).

Comment: I made some edits to your question, you can look at them to improve your use of MathJax. Specifically, don't write things like `$\int x dx$ $=$ $x^2/2$`. Write `$\int x dx = x^2/2$`

Comment: @AnneBauval Typo fixed. It has to be $0$ so you're saying use my first splitting up and then differentiate normally using FTC ? So because $e^{-t}$ is continuous on its domain I can apply the fundamental theorem of calculus ?

Comment: @AnneBauval For my definition we have been given the upper limit has to be $x$ and the lower limit has to be $0$, then for the second integral with limits $0$ and $-5$ the derivative is $0$ because it's a constant function.

Comment: "your definition" of what? Anyway, in the [fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Formal_statements), the lower bound does not neeed to be $0.$ (And that is a good thing, because it may apply to functions whose domain does not contain $0.$)

Comment: @AnneBauval You're right I think because all I need is $x$ to be the upper limit but I find it easier to explain with $0$ as the lower limit for the first integral. This is what the lecture notes say.

Comment: If your lecture notes say so, then they are bad. It is neither easier nor less easy to take the lower bound equal to $0$ than to any other fixed value, and (as said before) it may sometimes be impossible. Think of $\int_0^x\ln(t-1)\,\mathrm dt.$

Comment: @AnneBauval Okay I will use your method because mine is a bit unnecessary. Can I send you a private message please ?

Comment: @AnneBauval It's easier for me to type in private message because in the comment there won't be enough space for my full argument and the mathjax environment is harder :)

Answer (score 1):

Find a formula for the derivative function of $G:[-1,1]\to\Bbb R$, $G(x):=$ $\int_{-5}^{2x^4+x^2+1}{e^{-t^4}} \;dt$, for $x \in [-1,1].$

Solution: Let $C:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be given by $C(x):=\int_{-5}^{x}{e^{-t^4}}$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$. The function $c:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ given by $c(t)=e^{-t^4}$ for all $t \in \Bbb R$. The function $c$ is continuous as a composition of $t\mapsto e^t$ and $t\mapsto -t^4$ where first is an elementary function and second is a polynomial.

Hence, apply Fundamental Theorem of Calculus for continuous functions, which implies that $C$ is differentiable with $C'(x) = c(x) = e^{-x^4}$ for all $x\in \Bbb R$.

Now, observe that $G(x) = C(2x^4+x^2+1)$, so $G=C\circ g$, where $g(x):=2x^4+x^2+1$ is differentiable as a polynomial. Also, $C$ is differentiable by previous discussion using Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, so the chain rule implies that $G$ is differentiable with derivative:

$G'(x) = C'(g(x))g'(x)$ = $({e^{-(2x^4+x^2+1)^4}})(8x^3+2x)$ for all $x$ $\in [-1,1]$ as required. $\square$

**@AnneBauval you misunderstood the original question I think before because the domain of $G$ is already defined in the question to be [-1,1]. Is it okay to define $C$ and $c$ to have domains of $\Bbb R$ since I have defined them myself? *

Comment: This proof now seems ok to me. I did not misunderstand your original question and I am glad having helped you to solve it. You followed my advice not to get headache and define $C,$ $c$ and $g$ on $\Bbb R.$ If you insist on being completely rigorous in writing $G=C\circ g,$ define $g$ only on $[-1,1],$ and $C$ only on $g([-1,1]).$

Comment: Okay thanks for your help. I was getting confused because in lectures for $C$ and $g$ type questions we would just put the same domain as $G$, when we could just use $R$ for the domain of $C$ and $g$ regardless of the domain of $G$ like you said

Comment: @AnneBauval One more thing. On the final line of my proof I said for all $x \in [-1,1]$. Is this correct ? Or should it be $\Bbb R$?

Comment: $[-1,1]$ ($G$ is not defined outside, hence neither is $G'$).

Comment: For the other way you said define $g$ on $[-1,1]$ but I never defined the domain of $g$. If I define $C$ on $g([-1,1])$, do I define $c$ on $g([-1,1])$ as well ?

Comment: The domain of $g$ must be the same as the domain of $G$ if you want to be rigorous in writing $G=C\circ g.$ And $c$ must be defined not only on $g([-1,1])$ but on the interval $[-5,4]$ (or any superset of it), for $C(y)=\int_{-5}^yc$ to be defined for all $y\in g([-1,1])=[1,4].$

Answer (score 0):

Let $G:[-1,1]\to\Bbb R$, $G(x):=$ $\int_{-5}^{2x^4+x^2+1}{e^{-t^4}} \;dt$, for $x \in [-1,1].$

Solution: Let $C:[-1,1]\to\Bbb R$ be given by $C(x):=\int_{-5}^{x}{e^{-t^4}}$ for all $x \in [-1,1]$. The function $c:[-1,1]\to\Bbb R$ given by $c(t)=e^{-t^4}$ for all $t \in [-1,1]$. The function $c$ is continuous as a composition of $t\mapsto e^t$ and $t\mapsto -t^4$ where first is an elementary function and second is a polynomial.

Hence, apply Fundamental Theorem of Calculus for continuous functions, which implies that $C$ is differentiable with $C'(x) = c(x) = e^{-x^4}$ for all $x\in[-1,1]$.

Now, observe that $G(x) = C(2x^4+x^2+1)$, so $G=C\circ g$, where $g(x):=2x^4+x^2+1$ is differentiable as a polynomial. Also, $C$ is differentiable by previous discussion using Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, so the chain rule implies that $G$ is differentiable with derivative:

$G'(x) = C'(g(x))g'(x)$ = $({e^{-(2x^4+x^2+1)^4}})(8x^3+2x)$ for all $x$ $\in [-1,1]$ as required. $\square$

**Question: $-5$ is not in the domain $[-1,1]$, so what do I do ?**

Comment: Your computation is entirely valid provided you replace $[-1,1]$ by $\Bbb R$ for the domainsof $C$ and $c.$ $-5$ is not in the domain you chose for $G$ but this does not matter at all. As said to my first comment to your initial post, you are confusing that domain with the interval of integration.

Comment: @AnneBauval I can’t replace $[-1,1]$ because that’s the domain stated in the question. That’s my problem.

Comment: @AnneBauval Can you do that for me please in a reply because I don’t understand ? Thanks

Comment: You want $G=C\circ g$ to be defined on $[-1,1].$ Since $g([-1,1])=[0,5],$ your $C$ has to be defined on $[0,5]$ (at least). So, you need $C(y)=\int_{-5}^yc(t)\,\mathrm dt$ to be defined for all $y\in[0,5],$ i.e. your $c$ to be defined on $[-5,5]$ (at least). But to avoid headache, simply define $C$ and $c$ on $\Bbb R$ (without changing your formulas).

Comment: @AnneBauval Isn't $g([-1,1]) = [1,5]$?

Comment: @AnneBauval So I should define $C$ and $c$ on the real numbers ?

Comment: Sorry, $g([-1,1])=[1,4].$ So *$C$ has to be defined on $[1,4]$ at least*, and *$c$ defined on $[-5,4]$ at least*. You can as well not bother and define all your auxillary functions ($C$ and $c$ as I said, but also $g$ if you like) on $\Bbb R.$ (Not you *should* but you *may*.)

Comment: @AnneBauval Okay so I changed all the $C:[-1,1]-R$ and  $c:[-1,1]-R$ to $C:R-R$ and $c:R-R$. I also changed all for all $x \in [-1,1]$ and for all $t \in [-1,1]$ to for all $x \in R$. and for all $t \in R$ Is this correct to do ?

Comment: Yes, correct, and simpler than analyzing in detail the minimal intervals needed "at least".

Comment: @AnneBauval Okay cool. Just seems weird that for $C,c,g$ we could define the domain to be $R$. But for $G$ is only defined on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: @AnneBauval If I post a new answer with updated domains will you please check it for me ? Thanks